# OPENDJ: LDAP: SCHEMA: [Unable to register attribute type name with the server schema...]

Tags: ldap, schema, opendj, directory-server

I keep getting the following error on restart of the opendj service. `bin/stop-ds --restart`.

```
[20/Dec/2022:15:32:30 -0500] category=CORE severity=NOTICE msgID=134 msg=OpenDJ Server 4.4.11 (build 20210621115558, revision number 3f83673) starting up
[20/Dec/2022:15:32:30 -0500] category=CONFIG severity=WARNING msgID=761 msg=The config schema file '04-rfc2307bis.ldif' generated warning when trying to update schema with its content: [Unable to register attribute type name with the server schema because its OID 2.5.4.41 conflicts with the OID of an existing attribute type name]
```

`bin/stop-ds --restart`

`egrep -R 2.5.4.41 /opt/opendj/config/schema`

```
04-rfc2307bis.ldif:attributeTypes: ( 2.5.4.41 NAME 'name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 X-ORIGIN 'RFC 4519' X-SCHEMA-FILE '00-core.ldif' )
00-core.ldif:attributeTypes: ( 2.5.4.41 NAME 'name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 X-ORIGIN 'RFC 4519' X-SCHEMA-FILE '00-core.ldif' )
```

I've tried removing the duplicate attributeType with ldapmodify and manually removing from the schema files. The duplicates always come back.

Expected behavior
When restarting OpenDJ, there should be normal output and no WARNINGS about duplicate OIDs.

OS: RHEL 7.9

Version: 4.4.11

**Additional context**

I noticed the file /opt/opendj/config/upgrade/schem.ldif.current was not synced with my replica. I removed both files and created empty ones. Restart OpenDJ, the error goes away for a few minutes then comes back every time. What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for any confusion. I believe I've solved this as a "user error".

I had a custom schema file not prepended with "99-". After adding the correct prefix things seem to be working as expected. Closing.